# MikTex Download Failure - toptesi.tar.lzma

Tags: miktex

I try to install Complete MiKTeX 2.9 
But there is this:

```
Error: The operation could not be completed because the following file failed verification:

C:\...\mikTex\toptesi.tar.lzma
```

There is the same with the basic version.

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: It seems you have downloaded the files to your hard disk and trying to install from there. Some files are corrupted. Try downloading again.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I try downloading again, but there is the same

Comment: Try with a different MiKTeX repository … (and it would be nice, if you'd change your user name to a more expressive one).

Comment: I tried with the different repositories, but there is also the same error

Comment: The package seems to be broken. Make a bug report.

Answer (score 3):

Look up a different repository that lags behind a couple of days. 
Most of them have already copied the corrupted files (miktex-misc is also broken).
The list of repositories has 188 entries, ftp.neowiz.com and elena.aut.ac.nz are the ones which have files dated older than 02-NOV-2013. The kiwi server worked for me.

Comment: all the mirrors on the list have version 09-NOV-2013.  I guess my only option is to wait until this is fixed?